# How to Parse JSON array in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I was trying below code,where body is response from `HTTP GET`. When I tried to run it, I am getting below error.

> Cannot read property '`po_number`' of undefined

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "po_number": "PO1001",
                "product_id": "PD1001",
                "message": "Exists",
                "timestamp": "2016-05-01" 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to access `po_number`

```
var profile = JSON.parse(body);
console.log("profile: "+ profile.results.po_number);
```

I am getting `undefined` when i access above code

Comment: `profile.results` it's an array not an object, you have to use something like `profile.results[index].po_number`, `profile.results[0].po_number` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed one step. You missed the object `d` and that the `results` is an array. So first access the `0` indexed item.

You need to get via `profile.d.results[0].po_number`.

```js
const jsonObj = `{ "d": {
     "results": [
      {
          "po_number": "PO1001",
          "product_id": "PD1001",
          "message": "Exists",
          "timestamp": "2016-05-01" 
      }]
}}`;

var profile = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
console.log(profile.d.results[0].po_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var profile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0]))
console.log("profile: "+ profile.po_number)
```

Comment: Why would you stringify the data then parse it?

Answer (score 0):

**results** is an array.

To access po_number, you'll need to do something like:

```
console.log("profile: "+ profile.results[0].po_number)
```

Make sure you dynamically iterate the array to access that value.

Example (in underscore/lodash) :

```
_.each(profile.results, (result) => { 
  console.log("profile: " + result.po_number);
});
```